# Convergence in distribution of bernoulli rv over square root of uniform rv

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

This is a question from an old comprehensive exam:

> Let $U$ be a $\operatorname{Uniform}[0,1]$ random variable and let $X$ be a $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ random variable independent of $U$.  Let $Y=\frac{X}{\sqrt{U}}$.  If $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are iid as $Y$, show that $\frac{\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{n\log n}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable.

What I am being asked to prove seems like it can't be correct, since $\frac{\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{n\log n}}$ is nonnegative, and therefore $P\left(\frac{\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{n\log n}} < x\right) = 0$ whenever $x < 0$, which clearly does not converge to the normal distribution function.  What am I missing?

Comment: May X takes 1 -1 with prob 1/2. This is a wild ass guess but that seems reasonable.

Comment: That's a good thought--I'll try to work the problem that way to see if that was the intention.